# How to send json from Rails

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, json

From Python I make request to Rails app, and get this response:
    {u'answer': u'ok'}
and in Rails side code like that:
   @res = {'answer'=> 'ok'}
   render json: @res

May this problem on python side? Here code of python:

```py
import requests
import json
URL1 = 'http://'
PARAMS = {'login': 'asd'}
r = requests.get(url = URL1, params = PARAMS)
data = r.json()
print(data)
```

How I can get clear json

Answer (score 0):

You can try as `data = r.as_json`

Comment: You mean in python side? If yes, should I add some another lib for that?

Comment: I think you asked How to send json from Rails ? so you can send json from rails by using .as_json on your response.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifically parsing the JSON contained in the response body into Python objects using `r.json()`. Use `r.text` to see the textual representation of the response body.

Comment: actually I need JSON but without u'. By the way " u' " is not problem, interesting why this symbol is appear

Comment: Oh boy. 1) JSON is the string that is sent, available from `r.text`, as I said. `r.json()` _parses_ the JSON (string) into equivalent Python objects; the result is no longer JSON. Decide which you want. 2) `u` does not exist. In Python2 there is a difference between Unicode strings and ASCII strings; if you print out a string using a method that uses `repr()`, you will get a string literal, which will be `'foo'` for an ASCII string and `u'foo'` for a Unicode string; but if you print them as strings, you just get `foo` (without the quotes, without the leading `u` glyph).

Answer (score 0):

In a Rails controller you can do:

```
render :json => data.to_json and return
```

In the CLI you'd do:

```
puts data.to_json
```

Make sure to include json or a compatible gem in your CLI code.